# How to keep music playing continuously when switching scenes?

Tags: unity, c#, android, music

I added music to my game, but it restarts when transitioning between scenes. I want it to play continuously without interruption. What should I do?

Comment: I've linked this post to two earlier Q&A threads about playing music continuously across scene transitions. [Remember to search for your keywords before posting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+music+scene), to help find answers faster. If you need help applying the existing answers in your game, you can **edit your question** to have it re-opened for answers to solve that specific issue.